# System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path

Tags: asp.net, mapped-drive

I have 1 service app(asp.net) that will upload txt file.
I would like to upload the file to network share drive.
example of network mapped drive: Z:\HR\hr\t\clock.
If i run the web page throught visual web developer, it can successfully save the file.
but if i run the web page directly via IE, it cannot save.
I already set the network folder for everyone is full control right.
it throw an exception System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'Z:\HR\t\clock102528122011113418.txt'.

Thanks

Comment: When you map a network drive, this drive is mapped pr user. If you are logged in as "admin" then the IIS user (or applicationpool user) wont be able to use that share.
I don't know how you can fix this but I think that is your problem..

Answer (score 2):

That will be because of Security Contexts I would think.

Running it from VWD runs under your security context, running "directly from IE" will run under a different context (Traditionally, IUSR_MachineName)

One scenario you have an account that has permissions, the other you do not.

I would recommend creating a service account to do the work and give that the least permissions possible and go from there.